# Value of variable is not changing as intended

Tags: python, python-3.7

so what i want to do is to change the value of a variable (targetx), its initial value is assigned randomly `targetx = random.randrange(0,500,1)` 
the value can be anywhere between 0 to 500, need to change its value to 0 one step at a time e.i. 444,443,442...,0 onece the value reaches zero i want it to go back to 500 again one step a time,
here is what i have tried:

targeVel is number of steps, let's say it is in this case, once the value reaches 1 (or the value of targetVel) it stops and starts switching between `targetVel` and `targetVel*2`

```py
    if targetx >= 1 and moving == True:
        targetx-= targetVel
        if targetx <= 1:
            moving = False

    else:
        #targetx <= targetVel:
        targetx+= targetVel
        if targetx <= 500:
            moving = True
```

here is the entire code:

```
import random

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("name")

moving = True

shipx = 10
shipy = 10
shipVel = 2
shipWidth = 64
shipLength = 64

targetVel = random.randrange(1,3,1)
targetx = random.randrange(0,500,1)
targety = random.randrange(0,500,1)

shipImg = pygame.image.load('res/ufo.png')
targetImg = pygame.image.load('res/man.png')

def turnl():
    if targetx <= 0:
        targetx+= targetVel

def turnr():
    if targetx >= 500:
        targetx-= argetVel

def ship():
    win.blit(shipImg, (shipx, shipy))

def target():
    win.blit(targetImg, (targetx, targety))

run = True

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(0)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()




    if targetx >= 1 and moving == True:
        targetx-= targetVel
        if targetx <= 1:
            moving = False

    else:
        #targetx <= targetVel:
        targetx+= targetVel
        if targetx <= 500:
            moving = True

    print(targetx,targetVel)

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        shipx-= shipVel

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        shipx+= shipVel

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        shipy-= shipVel

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        shipy+= shipVel

    if shipx >= 500 -shipLength:
        shipx-= shipVel

    if shipx <= 0:
        shipx+= shipVel

    if shipy >= 500 -shipWidth:
        shipy-= shipVel

    if shipy <= 0:
        shipy+= shipVel

    win.fill((68, 154, 91))
    target()
    ship()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: How do you know it is not changing as intended? What is your expected output vs. actual output?

Comment: Could you please provide the initial declaration for targetx, moving an targetVel? And as @kaya3 said, what's the expected output for this script?

Comment: i need it to go from the initial value to 0 one step a time that is if the initial value us 4, the value should go 4,3,2,1,0 and then from zero it should go to 500 again the same way